# IOS IPAD UIpopovercontroller need to close and open on the same process

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

Actually i need to move the UIpopovercontroller while it's open but i found that we can't move it while its open the only thing we can do is to close it and then open it again, But again i found one more problem with this, When ever i try to dismis a popover and then open it again its wont open. Please take a look at my code.

```
CGRect cursor = [TextViewText menuPresentationRect];

    if ([PredictionPopover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [PredictionPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
[PredictionPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(cursor), CGRectGetMaxY(cursor), 1, 1) inView:TextViewText permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];

    } else {
        [PredictionPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(cursor), CGRectGetMaxY(cursor), 1, 1) inView:TextViewText permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

Can someone pelase tell me whats wrong am i doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by just stop the animation

```
CGRect cursor = [TextViewText menuPresentationRect];

    if ([PredictionPopover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [PredictionPopover dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];
[PredictionPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(cursor), CGRectGetMaxY(cursor), 1, 1) inView:TextViewText permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];

    } else {
        [PredictionPopover presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(cursor), CGRectGetMaxY(cursor), 1, 1) inView:TextViewText permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:NO];
    }
```